# <use> - SVG: Stroke of Circle overriding stroke of use element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Stroke of both `<use>` element ignored here. The stroke color of `<circle>` is set blue which is appearing on both `<use>` element too. Why?

I want different strock color of all of 3 these element. but it is not working.

```
<svg width="300" class="svg-elem" viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
  <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="blue"/>
   
  <use class="circle1" href="#myCircle" x="10" stroke="grey" fill="blue"/>
   
  <use href="#myCircle" x="20" fill="white" stroke="red"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Don't use a stroke for the circle. In the case you need a blue stroked circle as well, put the circle without a stroke attribute in a `<defs>` and `<use>` it with a blue stroke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `circle` still overriding the `<use>`.

[image]

You can consider using CSS variable to control stroke color like below.

```html
<svg width="300" class="svg-elem" viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">  
  <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" style="stroke:var(--stroke, blue)"/>
   
  <use class="circle1" href="#myCircle" x="10" style="--stroke:gray;" fill="blue"/>
   
  <use href="#myCircle" x="20" fill="white" style="--stroke:red;"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: I am facing same issue with use of CSS too.

Comment: doesn't solved your problem? as you can see it is working fine in the snippet. could you add more detail?